# python win32com, are objects automatically re-used?

Tags: python, com, pythoncom

The python code iterates over the paragraphs of a simple document (7 lines "Line 1", "Line 2" etc). I expect that each paragraph-object is unique, but actually I get duplicates, in this case `0x25173368`. What happens? It is completely against my intuition.

The code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.GetObject(Class="Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open("test.docx")

for para in doc.Paragraphs:
  print repr(para)
```

The output:

```
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Paragraph instance at 0x25173368>
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Paragraph instance at 0x25427240>
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Paragraph instance at 0x25173368>
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Paragraph instance at 0x25427280>
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Paragraph instance at 0x25173368>
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Paragraph instance at 0x25427320>
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Paragraph instance at 0x25173368>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration over `doc.Paragraphs` probably creates a Python wrapper object to each underlying COM object dynamically. Since you do not store `para` anywhere, the wrapper object is destroyed when it goes out of scope, and the next iteration may create a new object at the same memory address.

Try this instead and see if the result is different:

```
paras = list(doc.Paragraphs)
for para in paras:
    print repr(para)
```